# Programming MS Access report to filter on specific ID

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I have a recordset that I'm looping through and would like to create a report that displays information for each user ID in the recordset. I've found many posts that have helped me to write the code, but I cannot figure out why my code keeps opening the report with all user IDs instead of each user ID individually. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Public Function report()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strReportName As String
Dim fileName, pathName As String

pathName = "C:\Users\Joe\Documents"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Add_user, keyer FROM qryProductionReport;")

strReportName = "ProductionReport"

Do While Not rs.EOF
    DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, , "Add_user = " & rs!Add_user, acHidden
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, pathName & strReportName & rs!Keyer & ".PDF"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, strReportName
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

I made sure that my field name `Add_user` on the report matches the filter that I have in the `DoCmd.OpenReport` line. I'm using Access 2016. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Output access Report with Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302369/how-to-output-access-report-with-condition)

Comment: `DoCmd.OutputTo` doesn't care there's a filtered report open, it always prints the entire saved report. You can work around this by either binding the report to a query and adjusting that query, or using a filter with a tempvar in the report. I recommend that last approach, since it'll flexibly allow you to filter while allowing the full report to be opened and not adjusting the report or any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to modify your report to use a [`TempVars`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tempvars) criteria
(e.g. `[TempVars]![userId]`) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224016/78522). 
You can then use it like this:

```
Public Function report()

Dim rs As Recordset, strReportName As String
Dim fileName as String, pathName As String

pathName = "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Add_user, keyer FROM qryProductionReport;")
strReportName = "ProductionReport"

Do While Not rs.EOF
    TempVars("userId") = rs!Add_user
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, pathName & strReportName & rs!Keyer & ".PDF"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```